# How can I read from a serial port in Android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, can-bus

I'm very new to Android app development and Android Studio and I'm currently working on developing an app for an Android tablet that can read CAN messages from an STM device. However, before I can do that, I need to establish communication with the device via a serial port. We've already attempted using Bluetooth, but unfortunately, it's not possible due to the carbon fiber dash.

In order to achieve this, I'm looking for guidance on how to read from a serial port in Android, and I'm also open to any suggestions regarding the necessary API or SDK that I might need.

Thank you for your assistance!

My team has tried to use Bluetooth in the past but due to the way carbon fiber works with that type of radio wave it does not work

Comment: By "serial port" you ben USB? So you have an USB-CAN adapter? Have you searched for `Android USB API`? Then you might have come across this link: https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/usb

Comment: I have not seen that one but ill look into it. Thank you